# Can you do a group Google chat with Messages?

Tags: messages, google-hangouts

How do you do a group Google chat (Hangouts) with iOS Messages? Specifically I would like to do a group chat via iOS Messages with multiple people who use Google Hangouts either where they initiate the group chat or I do.

Thanks all for any ideas or suggestions!

Comment: Do you have the Google hangouts app?  With the app It's really simple to do this, so simple there would never be need for a question.  Start new conversation with the "+" and click new group on the next screen.

Comment: When you say "Messages" are you referring to the iOS/Mac app called Messages, or are you simply meaning the generic "messages" i.e. a group text chat? The reason I ask is you capitalized it the first time but not the second, and also, unless this is occurring in an app being used on Apple hardware, the question is off-topic for this site.

Comment: Thanks Tyson, that is great! Do you know of a way without the Google Hangouts App via iOS Messges instead?

Comment: @tubedogg From [his latest comment](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/251253/can-you-do-a-group-google-chat-with-messages#comment312567_251253) and [his latest edit](http://apple.stackexchange.com/revisions/251253/2), he's specifically saying the iOS Messages app.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a group conversation in Messages, but there's no way to automatically have it set up based on a group from Hangouts.

To start a group conversation in Messages for iOS, tap on the paper/pencil icon at the upper left of the threads list, then simply enter as many contact names or phone numbers as you like. When you send a message, it will create the group automatically.